# IntelliJ file excluded from search, how to un-exclude?

Tags: intellij-idea

I have somehow managed to exclude my `webpack` configuration from IntelliJ search results. It also now has a little cross on it as shown below. How do I re-add the content of this file to search results?

I have tried excluding the file from the Project Settings/ Modules/ Excluded files, and then removing it to clear the cache, but it still gets excluded. Thanks!

[image: Example]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check your `.idea/workspace.xml` - do you have this `.js` file listed in `<component name="TypeScriptGeneratedFilesManager">` section there, like:

```
<component name="TypeScriptGeneratedFilesManager">
    <option name="version" value="1" />
    <option name="exactExcludedFiles">
      <list>
        <option value="$PROJECT_DIR$/path/to/webpack.config.js" />
        ...
      </list>
    </option>
  </component>
```

Comment: Amazing! That fixed it.